# $ x^2+(a-b)x+1=a+b$, seemingly simple but interesting

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The roots of the Eqation:  $$ x^2+(a-b)x+1=a+b$$
are real and distinct for all real value of $x$, I have to prove that $a>0$
Now obviously, the discriminant has to be more than $0$ so i tried it but then, i was left with:$$a^2+b^2-2ab-4+4a+4b>0$$
How do i go about solving this problem, any ideas? or is there another way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean for "all real values of $b$"?

Comment: The task is unclear to me, do you mean: "given $a>0$, prove that the roots of the equation are real and distinct"? Or: "given that the roots of the equation are real and distinct, prove $a>0$"?

Comment: In both cases, there are counter-examples :  
If $a = 1/2$ and $b = 0$, then $\Delta = -\frac{7}{4} < 0$ and the roots aren't real though $a >0$.  
If $a = -5$ and $b = 0$, then the roots are $2$ and $3$. So $a< 0$ though the roots are real and distinct.

Comment: How do i prove to mathematically?

Answer (score 0):

Substituting $a=u+v$ and $b=u-v$,
$$a^2+b^2-2ab-4+4(a+b)=(u+v)^2+(u-v)^2-2(u^2-v^2)+8u\\
=4v^2+8u\geq0
$$
$$\therefore u\geq-\frac{v^2}{2}$$

Therefore, $(v,u)$ should be above this parabola.

Comment: no i should prove that $a>0$ given that the equation is real and distinct